# free-jQgrid throws SystemOutofMemoryException if data count is more than 10K

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, free-jqgrid

Recently, I have started getting an issue related to "SystemOutOfMemoryException" in free-jQgrid. The version that I am using is 4.15.4 with MVC 5 and Sql Server DB queries for bringing data . The reason I have found is growth of the data. If data is around 10K with `LoadOnce:true` at that point it works without any issue. But when more data comes then it started throwing this issue.
I am getting all data from database in one go and loads it to the grid.

Here is some pieces of controller code:

```
        public JsonResult GetDataWRTLanguage(string searchKey)
        {

            FormBL formsbl = new FormBL();
            List<Form_Check> lstPPVM = new List<Form_Check>();
            filter f = new filter();
            string returnedLangCode = "";

            if (searchKey != "")
            {
                TempData["LanguageCode"] = searchKey;
            }

            if (Convert.ToString(TempData["LanguageCode"]) != "")
            {
                returnedLangCode = Convert.ToString(TempData["LanguageCode"]);
                TempData.Keep("LanguageCode");
            }
            else{
                returnedLangCode = searchKey;                
            }


            lstPPVM = formsbl.getDataWithLanguage(returnedLangCode);
            //var newList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstPPVM);
            int page = 1, rows = 1;
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = lstPPVM.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            var Results = lstPPVM.AsQueryable();
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = Results
            };
            var jsonResult = Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

Here is jqgrid code

```
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
            url: '/MView/GetDataWRTLanguage?searchKey=' + LanguageId + "",
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: [*more than 15*]
            colModel: [*body of all columns with search*]
            loadComplete: function () {                
                if ($('#grid').getGridParam('records') === 0) {
                    oldGrid = $('#GridIdb2 tbody').html();
                    $(".jqgfirstrow").css("height", "1px");                   
                }
                else {
                    oldGrid = "";
                }
                this.p.lastSelected = lastSelected; 
                var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('majorgridInfo'));
                if (obj != undefined || obj != undefined || obj != null || obj != null) {
                    jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({ rowNum: obj.rowNum.toString() });
                    var grid = $("#grid");
                    jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({ rowNum: obj.rowNum }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    $('.ui-pg-selbox').val(obj.rowNum);
                }
            },
            onPaging: function (pgbtn) {
                Selected_RowList = $('.ui-pg-selbox').val();
                saveGridParameters();
            },
            forceClientSorting: true,
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
            width: '100%',
            scrollbar: true,
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            editurl: "/MajorsView/EditParticipantRecords/",
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            height: '480px',
            //width: '100%',
            //maxHeight: 980,
            //pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 25,     //// adjust height of Jqgrid
            rowList: [25, 100, 200, 500, 1000,10000],       ////adjust height of Jqgrid
            ignoreCase: true,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            hidegrid: true, //To disable collapsing
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            caption: "<i class='fa fa-users'></i> Participant List",
            multiSort: true,
            sortname: 'ReferenceId',
            sortOrder: 'asc',
            rowattr: function (rd) {
                if (rd.Check === "true") { 
                    return { "class": "state_inactive" };
                }
            },

            multiselect: false,
            emptyrecords: "No records to display",
            jsonReader:
            {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "ReferenceId"
            },
            inlineEditing: { keys: true, defaultFocusField: "ReferenceId", focusField: "ReferenceId" },
          });
```

Here I also used JsonMaxLength property but it still throws error.
I've seen that [even 60K data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975627/how-to-show-too-many-rows-data-with-json-in-jqgrid) is still working fine with it but for me it starts giving error on more than 10K data.

Additional questions: Should I use Server side jqgrid implementation, if yes then how can i modify [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313780/how-to-do-server-side-sorting-paging-in-jqgrid-in-asp-net-mvc) to newer version of MVC and jQgrid version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of posts regarding server side pagination in jqGrid. You can search the web too. By example [this one](https://moinulmithu.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/jqgrid-with-asp-net-mvc-5-application/)

Comment: Hello and Thanks Tony for taking time to provide your input. Glad to e-meet you. Yes, I have searched web for the same and ended up getting jquery-jqgrid or jquerygrid related examples. Which I thought not matching with free-jqgrid. Though, I read Oleg's post about server side pagination in free-jqgrid but it is bit old now. So, thought to ask here. Another thing, I wanted to know why the error is throwing in the free-jQgrid.